# How to use StartActivityResult() outside activity or fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, error-handling

Basically i have a function to open camera by intent, and i am trying to add that function to Extention fuction file but getting an error saying "create function startActivityForResult". So can anyone help how to achieve this ?

```
private fun imageChooser() {

    //passing intent.

    val i = Intent ()
    i.type = "image/*"
    i.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT


   //Getting error here when i am pasting this code in a different file 
    called extention function.

    startActivityForResult (i, 0)
}
```

Comment: at first - post your code in "copyable" way, no one will be rewritting your lines from picture. second - post all related code, not only single method, thats not sufficient

Comment: "i am trying to add that function to Extention fuction file" -- you did not create an extension function of a class that has a `startActivityForResult()` function. Beyond that, please [follow the instructions](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `startActivityForResult()` in a non-activity class you must use the a reference to an activity.

Pass the activity as a parameter to the function you are using and use it in the non-activity class:

```
private fun imageChooser(activity: Activity) {
    val intent = Intent()
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent,0)
}
```

or activity:

```
this.startActivityForResult(intent, 0)
```

or fragment:

```
activity?.startActivityForResult(Intent(), 0)
requireActivity().startActivityForResult(Intent(), 0)
```

***IMPORTANT***

`startActivityForResult()` is **deprecated**.

Follow [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) from the official documentation

Comment: Never create instances of `ComponentActivity` directly.

Comment: Why ? Can you explain more ? Removing it from the answer immediately, thanks!

Comment: Never create instances of `Activity` or any subclass of `Activity` directly. Activities need to be instantiated by the framework for them to work properly, including the ability to start other activities.

Comment: Removed from the answers, is it good now ? Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: yes now passing activity as an argument has solved my problem